# regex to match entire unicode words which contains certain unicode character

Tags: javascript, regex

For example, match all cyrillic words, which contain symbol `ь`

Comment: Use [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/).

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach would be splitting the sentence to get every word separately, then use `Array#filter` to filter out every word containing specified character, in this case - `ь`.

```js
var str = 'something else herь',
    res = str.split(' ').filter(v => v.indexOf('ь') > -1);
    
    console.log(res);
```

Comment: What if there is punctuation "glued" to the words? BTW, `herь` looks extremely funny in Russian :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Does it mean something wrong? I have just typed it randomly ;p And about your question, can you provide me some example, because I don't really get it.

Comment: Check [Google Translate](https://translate.google.pl/#auto/en/%D1%85%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F). And a sample: `День,который запомнят все.` - your solution will return 2 words `День,который` as one entry.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I could check if there are any commas in the string and if so, split it again, but what's the point? `День,который запомнят все.` is actually punctuationally improper (there should be a whitespace after the comma). Do you mean the idiotproof rule?

Comment: The point is that you cannot split with whitespace in an arbitrary text when you need to obtain whole words.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are a very wise man, teach me something new. How do I obtain whole words properly?

Comment: `XRegExp('(^|[^_0-9\\pL])(\\pL+)(?![_0-9\\pL])','g');` (to imitate an ASCII word boundary).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Looks pretty scary. I'm trying to use it on random strings, getting `null` in return ;o

Comment: See my comment to the question first.

Comment: JS by itself has no notion of Unicode word boundary. Unicode word `\w` characters all by themselves comprise 119,037 codepoints. It's inverse `\W` comprise 992,960 codepoints.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks Wiktor, I get it now.

Comment: This isn't exactly the complete story of Unicode word boundary's.

Answer (score 0):

If you need just Cyrillic script letters only, it would have to be done  using
whitespace boundary's.
The word boundary would be a very *large* regex.
Remember, Cyrillic can be interspersed with Latin so I guess it's moot.

This will get you Cyrillic words with the
`U+00044C    ь    CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER SOFT SIGN`

`/(?:\s|^)[\u0400-\u0484\u0487-\u052F\u1C80-\u1C88\u1D2B\u1D78\u2DE0-\u2DFF\uA640-\uA69F\uFE2E-\uFE2F]*\u044c[\u0400-\u0484\u0487-\u052F\u1C80-\u1C88\u1D2B\u1D78\u2DE0-\u2DFF\uA640-\uA69F\uFE2E-\uFE2F]*(?!S)/`

Expanded

```
 (?: \s | ^ )
 [\u0400-\u0484\u0487-\u052F\u1C80-\u1C88\u1D2B\u1D78\u2DE0-\u2DFF\uA640-\uA69F\uFE2E-\uFE2F]* 
 \u044c 
 [\u0400-\u0484\u0487-\u052F\u1C80-\u1C88\u1D2B\u1D78\u2DE0-\u2DFF\uA640-\uA69F\uFE2E-\uFE2F]* 
 (?! S )
```